# Yii2 console commands are just echoing list of commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, yii, yii2, console

All of my Yii console commands are just echoing this:

```
This is Yii version 2.0.49.

The following commands are available:

- asset                        Allows you to combine and compress your JavaScript and CSS files.
    asset/compress (default)   Combines and compresses the asset files according to the given configuration.
    asset/template             Creates template of configuration file for [[actionCompress]].

...

To see the help of each command, enter:

  yii help <command-name>
```

And it's not command syntax, even if I with this command: `php yii help serve` I still get just a list with available commands and nothing was executed. Can someone give me a clue why is this happening?